# Pythonic way to smart-rename files for record-keeping sake?

Tags: python, performance, cross-platform, automated-tests, file-rename

Using IronPython 2.6 (I'm new), I'm trying to write a program that opens a file, saves it at a series of locations, and then opens/manipulates/re-saves those. It will be run by an upper-level program on a loop, and this entire procedure is designed to catch/preserve corrupted saves so my company can figure out why this glitch of corruption occasionally happens.

I've currently worked out the Open/Save to locations parts of the script and now I need to build a function that opens, checks for corruption, and (if corrupted) moves the file into a subfolder (with an iterative renaming applied, for copies) or (if okay), modifies the file and saves a duplicate, where the process is repeated on the duplicate, sans duplication.

I tell this all for context to the root problem. **In my situation, what is the most pythonic, consistent, and windows/unix friendly way to move a file (corrupted) into a subfolder while also renaming it based on the number of pre-existing copies of the file that exist within said subfolder?**

*In other words:* 
In a folder structure built as:
`C:\Folder\test.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test01.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test02.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test03.txt`
How to I move `test.txt` such that:
`C:\Folder\Subfolder`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test01.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test02.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test03.txt`
`C:\Folder\Subfolder\test04.txt`
In an automated way, so that I can loop my program overnight and have it stack up the corrupted text files I need to save? *Note: They're not text files in practice, just example.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are going to use the convention of incrementally suffinxing numbers to the files:

```
import os.path
import shutil

def store_copy( file_to_copy, destination):
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext( os.path.basename(file_to_copy)
    existing_files = [i for in in os.listdir(destination) if i.startswith(filename)]
    new_file_name = "%s%02d%s" % (filename, len(existing_files), extension)
    shutil.copy2(file_to_copy, os.path.join(destination, new_file_name)
```

There's a fail case if you have subdirectories or files in *destination* whose names overlap with the source file, ie, if your file is named 'example.txt' and the destination containst 'example_A.txt' as well as 'example.txt' and 'example01.txt'  If that's a possibility you'd have to change the test in the   *existing files =* line to something more sophisticated

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I was looking for. It formats the strings, it iterates, it's everything I had wanted but would take days to figure out myself. Upvote and answered!